# missing column in dataframe python

Tags: python, data-analysis

ive been trying to prepare this dataframe to use it in bulding a regression model
for some reason the date column is gone. when i type df.info() i get that there is an only one column.

```
    df=dataframe.copy()
df = df.groupby('date_')\
.agg({'duration_seconds': [('co1', 'sum')] }).reset_index()
df.columns = ['date_','Total_watch_time_in_seconds']
df['Total_watch_time_in_houres']=df['Total_watch_time_in_seconds']/3600
df = df.drop(columns=['Total_watch_time_in_seconds'])
df = df[(df['date_'] >= '2018-01-01')]
df = df.set_index('date_')
df.sort_index(inplace=True)
df=df.asfreq('b')
df=df.fillna(method='ffill')
df.info()
```

yet when i print head() it shows two column.

Comment: You set 'date_' as index, thus it's not column anymore. If you would run "df.reset_index().info()" you would see it again.

Comment: how do i go around it ? i need to use it as column. how do i fix it with keeping the logic what can i use instead ?

Comment: I believe you can still use it as a column, just not access it with `df[col_name]`. For example, where you used `df[df['date'] >= x]` when it was not index, you can now use `df[df.index >= x]`.

Comment: @leena depends on what you need. If you don't want it as index, then do not do this "df.set_index('date_')" if you need it as index, but later want to see revert and have it as column then do "df.reset_index()"